# how to descript ioncube zend file

Tags: php

i have a file that i have decoded and it has this unwanted code displayed as

```
while ( $rows4 = _obfuscate_DRAkJDUkWzwLJBQoBBMhGiQeGygLLiIÿ( $result4 ) )
{
    echo "                      <option value=\"";
    echo $rows4['serverid'];
    echo "\"";
    if ( $serverid == $rows4['serverid'] )
    {
        echo " selected=\"selected\"";
    }
    echo ">#";
    echo $rows4['serverid'];
    echo " - ";
    echo $rows4['name'];
    echo "</option>\r\n                      ";
}
```

..please help me as fast as you can
thank kyou in advance

Comment: Take an educated guess!

Comment: @RiggsFolly i cannot understand this characters ..my whole file is decoded correctly except these characters

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to decode ioncude obfiscation. But it looks like a command to retrieve data from query.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you please a link to encode ioncube zend files.

Comment: just google ioncube you get this : http://www.ioncube.com/